# Skype URI for SMS doesn't seem to work on iPhone/iPod

Tags: ios, sms, uri, skype

I'm trying to use the Skype SMS URI from an iOS (iPhone/iPod Touch) app, i.e. opening the `skype:+33123456789?sms` URI. It works great on my Mac, with Skype installed (typing `open 'skype:+33153928448?sms'` in the terminal or in a URI bar will bring Skype and start composing the text message).

However, it fails miserably on the iPhone, where it brings up Skype and just starts an endless loop of "Opening this page in Safari will quit Skype" messages (by endless, I mean: if you click on "Open in Safari", then you get the same warning again and again forever).

How can I troubleshoot that? Am I doing it wrong? My current Objective-C code is:

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:+33153928448?sms"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be broken on Skype's end. I would try to avoid it.

You could also test this by pasting that URL into Mobile Safari and see what happens.

Try removing the `?sms`.

Comment: Removing the `?sms` doesn't work. I can initiate calls (with `?call`), but I want to send SMS!

Answer (score 1):

Its not actually a bug. We dont currently support SMS sending universally across all platforms via URIs. You can find out what is supported via this page: http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference

if we add URI support for sending sms messages universally then that page will be updated, however I have no timescales on when this may be added.

Thanks

Allen Smith
Skype Developer Community Manager

Answer (score 0):

The only method that's currently supported in IOS is the ?call method. ?call&video=true DOES NOT WORK on IOS - but ?call without the video=true works the same way. The IOS support seems to be lagging behind the other devices and the documentation on the Skype website is INCORRECT.

I learned this after a lot of headaches!!!